# How to write maintainable, not brittle, unit tests for a GUI?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic, user-interface, maintainability

I tried writing UI unit tests for my GUI apps and I face the problem that, while they work well when I initially write them, they turn out to be brittle and they break whenever the design changes (that is, quite often). I'm struggling to find a set of guidelines that would lead me to having maintainable unit tests for the GUI.

For now, one thing that I discovered is that tests saying "this component should show its input data somewhere" are good (and that's very easy with HTML). Tests checking for a specific state of a specific part of the component are usually brittle. Tests going like click-click-click-expect, that try to follow the user behaviour and the underlying business logic (which is the most important part) usually turn out to be brittle. How do I write good tests?

---

To be more precise, I'd like to know some patterns about **what** could I test in my UI, not exactly **how** to test it. Naming conventions and fixed identifiers are good, but don't solve the core problem, which is, that GUIs change a lot. I'd like to test the behaviours that are most unlikely to change. **How to find the right thing to test?**

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: You edited the question to be about UI testing in general, while I originally asked about unit testing. I find integration tests harder to maintain and I prefer unit tests over them, whenever possible.

Comment: I think this is part of the problem though, fundamentally you can't really test any interface by unit testing alone as their raison d'etre is to interface to something. GUIs are no different in this respect.

Comment: m01, you can change it back.  I think of UI tests as usually being integrated tests.  The tests tend to rely on the seed and fixture data being present and the UI working with them.  If you have true UI tests that don't rely on any other data that is excellent.  However I've found this to be relatively rare.

Comment: related but not a duplicate since this is about gui tests: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109703/how-to-avoid-fragile-unit-tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common problem with GUI tests... The main reason these tests are considered brittle is because **they cannot survive a change in the GUI that is not a change in requirements**. You should strive to structure your test code in such a way that a change in the GUI is isolated to a single place in the tests.

As an example, consider a test that is worded as:

> When the user enters '999' into the phonenumber field and clicks the save button, the error message popup should say 'invalid phone number'.

Plenty of room here for this test to break when you rework the interface, even if the requirement for the validation stays.

Now, lets put this into a little alternative wording:

> When the user enters '999' as a phonenumber and saves the profile page, it should show an error that says 'invalid phone number'

The test is the same, the requirements are the same, but this kind of test will survive a makeover for your UI. You will need to change code, obviously, but the code will be isolated. Even if you have ten or twenty such tests for your profile page and you move your errormessage-displaying validation logic from javascript-alerts to jquery-popups for example, you only need to change the single test part that checks error messages.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem.  I would pay attention to:

- How you name elements

  Use css id or class to identify elements.  Favor using the CSS ID when the object is unique.  Consider the framework you are using, for example with Ruby on Rails the `name` attribute is assigned automatically and can (non-intuitively) be better than using the css id or class
- How you identify elements.

  Avoid positional identifiers like `table/tr/td/td` in favor of forms such as `td[id="main_vehicle"` or `td[class='alternates']`.  Consider using data attributes when appropriate.  Even better try to avoid layout tags such as `<td>` altogether so for the above you could either add a span and use that, e.g. `<span id="main_vehicle">` or a wildcard selector such as `*[id="main_vehicle"]` where the `*` could now be a div, span, td, etc.
- Using test specific [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) that are only used for qa and testing.
- Avoid unnecessary qualification for elements.
  You might find yourself using the following:

  `body.main div#vehicles > form#vehicle input#primary_vehicle_name`

  However this requires that input field to remain in a form with an exact id of vehicle and on a page with a body that has a class of main and a div with an id of vehicles that has an immediate child of a form with an id of vehicle.  Any change to any of that structure and the test breaks.  In this case you might find that

  `input#primary_vehicle_name`

  is enough to uniquely identify the element.
- Avoid tests that refer to visible text.  The text on the page that is shown to the user usually changes over time as the site is maintained and updated, so use identifiers such as css id and css class or data attributes.  Elements such as `form`, `input` and `select` used in forms are also good parts of identifying elements, usually in combination with id or class, e.g. `li.vehicle` or `input#first-vehicle`
  You can also add your own identifiers, e.g. `<div data-vehicle='dodge'>`.  This way you can avoid using the element IDs or classes, which are likely to be changed by developers and designers.  I've actually found over time that its better to just work with developers and designers and come to agreement over names and scopes.  It is hard.
- How fixed data is maintained.

  Similar to identifying actual elements, try to avoid in-line hard coded selector identifying values in favor of page objects - small pieces of text that are held in variables or methods and thus can be reused and also maintained centrally.  Examples of javascript variables following this pattern for hard-coded values:

  ```
  storedVars["eqv_auto_year"] = "2015";
  storedVars["eqv_auto_make_1"] = "ALFA ROMEO";
  storedVars["eqv_auto_make_2"] = "HONDA";`
  ```

  More on page objects at [selenium wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and [selenium docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern)
- Communication with developers.

  Regardless of technical approach in terms of 'developers make changes and break the QA automation' that is a workflow issue.  You need to make sure that: everyone is one the same team; developer run the same integrated tests; standards are agreed on and followed by both groups; the definition of done includes running and possibly updating the UI tests; developers and tester pair on test plans and both attend ticket grooming (if doing Agile) and talk about UI testing as part of the grooming. 
  You should make sure that whatever approach and strategy you use for naming is coordinated with application developers.  If you don't get on the same page you'll like clash over object naming.
  Some examples of page object methods that I recently created for a ruby project:

  ```
  def css_email_opt_in_true
    'auto_policy[email_opt_in][value=1]'
  end 

  def css_phone_opt_in
    '*[name="auto_policy[phone_opt_in]"]'
  end 

  def css_phone_opt_in_true
    'input[name=phone_opt_in][value=true]'
  end 

  def css_credit_rating
    'auto_policy[credit_rating]'
  end
  ```

  Here's the same page objects as javascript variables:

  ```
  storedVars["css_email_opt_in"] = "css=*[name='auto_policy[email_opt_in]']";
  storedVars["css_phone_opt_in"]="css=*[name='auto_policy[phone_opt_in]']";
  storedVars["css_phone_opt_in_true"]="css=input[name='phone_opt_in'][value=true]";
  storedVars["css_credit_rating"]="css=select[name='auto_policy[credit_rating]']";
  ```

Comment: These are useful hints, and I actually already follow most of them. My problem was, that I write tests for some button, and then this button gets removed while the same action is handled from somewhere else. Or the button stays there, but the label changes, and the button runs also some additional action.

Comment: Ahh, that's good to know.  Yeah for that stuff I would focus on workflow and organizational qa-developer interaction

Comment: I'm also posting info for the others who find your question and may not have all the pieces in place that you have or may not even know about them.

Comment: I've expanded my last bulllet point based on your feedback.

Comment: And I've updated the parts about naming and identifying elements and about not using visible text.

Comment: and added a bullet point on avoiding overly specific identification which leads to brittleness.

Comment: Why would you ever use `td[id="main_vehicle"]` over `#main_vehicle`? It seems like horrible practice for IDs to be used for more than one thing. As another aside, it seems like a more typical way to write this would be as `td#main_vehicle`. Similarly, instead of `td[class='alternates']`, `td.alternatives` is more typical.

Comment: Yeah sure, shorthand is great.  Any other feedback?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why people developed things like MVC, MVP and presenter first, and similar design patterns, was to separate the business logic from the user interface.

Obviously, the view part can only be tested by starting the program, and checking what it shows - in other words, it can only be tested in acceptance tests.

On the other hand, testing the business logic can be done in unit tests. And that is the answer to your question. Test everything in the model, and if you can and want, you can also test the controller's code.

---

> GUIs change a lot

That can only happen when you got changing requirements. When a requirement changes, there is no way around it, except to modify the code. If you manage to create good design and architecture, the change will not propagate in many places.

Comment: I think it's a good point. Maybe I'm just doing MVC wrong :) Btw, I believe that changing requirements are unavoidable when you develop a web platform for lots of users. You don't know how your users will behave until they start using the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

GUI interaction tests should be no more or less brittle than any other kinds of tests. That is; if your application is changing in some way, the tests need to be updated to reflect that.

As a comparison:

**Unit Test**

*Original*: `validateEmail()` should throw an `InvalidData` exception. Which is correctly covered in your unit test.

*Change*: `validateEmail()` should throw an `InvalidEmail` exception. Now your test is incorrect, you update it, and everything is green again.

**GUI Test**

*Original*: Entering an invalid email will result in a popup error box containing "Invalid data entered". Correctly detected by your tests.

*Change*: Entering an invalid email will result in an inline error containing "Invalid email entered". Now your test is incorrect, you update it, and everything is green again.

---

Remember that you're testing for inputs and outputs - some well defined behaviour. Regardless of if it's a GUI test or a Unit test or an Integration test, etc.